# How to use Math.max, etc. as higher-order functions

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

In short, this works:

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce(function (a, b) { return Math.max(a, b); });
=> 3
```

But this doesn't:

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce(Math.max);
=> NaN
```

Pure puzzlement.

This is in Firefox 3.5.9, which I presume is using the [mozilla standard implementation of reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/reduce), FWIW.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: You're not trying to use Math.max as a higher-order function, but to use it as an argument to a higher-order function. Using it as a higher order function would mean to use it with arguments that are functions (or to use it so that it returns a function).

Comment: @sepp2k Perfectly fair nitpick.  :-)

Comment: Reduce spec is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: That's a little disappointing. In Scheme, one of the main sources of inspiration for JavaScript, you can even use operators like + or * as arguments to "reduce," e.g. `(reduce + '(1 2 3 4 5))`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Math.max` can be used as a higher-order function. The problem is `.reduce` will call the function with 4 arguments:

```
Math.max(accumulator, value, index, the_array)
```

here is `the_array` is an array, so `Math.max` returns NaN. I don't think there's simpler way to discard the last 2 arguments.

Comment: That's what I get for not reading the MDC docs closely enough.  Crazy idea of a reduce fn, IMO, but hey, it's javascript! ;-)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.max.apply(Math, [1, 2, 3]);
//3
```

Comment: Mind that this might not work for large arrays >=65536. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Using_apply_and_built-in_functions

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a higher order use, but this also works:

```
Math.max(...myArray);
```