# Why can't I write [1,2,3].reduce(Math.max) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use Math.max, etc. as higher-order functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856696/how-to-use-math-max-etc-as-higher-order-functions)

Using Mozilla's Javascript 1.6 array 'extension' functions (map, reduce, filter etc.), why is it that the following works as expected:

```
var max = [1,2,3].reduce(function(a,b) { return Math.max(a,b); });
```

But the following does not work (it produces NaN):

```
var max2 = [1,2,3].reduce(Math.max);
```

Is it because Math.max is a variadic function?

Comment: Not entirely on topic, but if you want to easily reduce an Array to its max value, you can use `.apply()` on `Math.max`. `var max = Math.max.apply(null, [1,2,3,4]);`

Answer (score 18):

`Math.max` does not know what to do with all the extra variables `function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array)` mainly that array at the end.

```
[].reduce.call([1,2,3,6],function(a,b) { return Math.max(a,b); });
```

This works and uses [.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: Wait, I see... I forgot there are 'extra' parameters passed to the function passed to reduce.  So max is trying to find the maximum on these extra parameters as well.

Comment: right and the `Math.max(1, [1,2,3])` is `NaN`

Comment: Why would you use .call() if you're going to pass an array as the `this` value? That's just an over-complicated way of doing what the OP already showed in the question.